# replace 1 string line to 2 string lines by using strrep in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have one text file as below.

[image]

I want to change the high lighted string line like below.

[image]

I could replace one line by using 'strrep' function like below.

```
fid=fopen('a.bdf');
A=fread(fid,'uint8=>char')';
B=strrep(A,'PSHELL   1       1      15.      1               1',['PSHELL   1       1      20.      1               1']);
```

But, I don't know how to replace one string line as two string lines by using strrep.

I just made a copy and paste like below.

```
fid=fopen('a.bdf');
    A=fread(fid,'uint8=>char')';
    B=strrep(A,'PSHELL   1       1      15.      1               1',['PSHELL   1       1      20.      1               1
PSHELL   2       1      2.      1               1']);
```

But, It's not working.

How can I do replace this string line by using 'strrep'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a newline character **'\r\n'** (can vary depending on your operating system) to your new substring like

```
B=strrep(A,'PSHELL   1       1      15.      1               1',['PSHELL   1       1      20.      1               1\r\nPSHELL   2       1      2.      1               1']);
```

And bear in mind that when you want to write to your file you have to use

```
fid=fopen('a.bdf','r+');
```

And with your approach you have to overwrite the original file with the new content in B.

**EDIT: Full Code**

```
fid=fopen('a.bdf','r+');
A=fread(fid,'uint8=>char')';
B=strrep(A,'PSHELL   1       1      15.      1               1','PSHELL   1       1      20.      1               1\r\nPSHELL   2       1      2.      1               1');
frewind(fid);
fprintf(fid,B);
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: @김갑수 I used `frewind(fid); fwrite(fid,B); fclose(fid);`, which worked like a charm for me.

Comment: I have added the code. I used `fprintf` instead of `fwrite`. Sorry for that mistake.